# Ruby On Rails Ajax Submit submitting twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I decided to make a blog in RoR and all is good I got the comments to submit and what not but when I went to "update" the submit method to allow for the page not to be refreshed when the comment is posted (ajax) however now whenever I go to post a comment on the pages for some reason it loops the send from the comment submit and I get two comments with the same message appearing at the same time.

```
   <h2>Comments</h2>
 <div id="comments">
   <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
 </div>

 <%= form_for [@post, Comment.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
     <%= f.text_area :body %>
   </p>
   <p><%= f.submit "Add comment", disable_with: "Adding Comment..." %></p>
 <% end %>
```

That is the show point, as you can see I tried to see if disabling the button with disable_with would help but it has not.

and below is the comment_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create!(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @post }
        format.js
      end
   end

        private

        def comment_params
                params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :post_id)
        end
  end
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have two sets of precompiled assets running locally:.

Try this on your machine:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Happens to me all the time.

Comment: Yep that was it thank you. Apparently I can only accept an answer as the solution in 10 minutes but that was it.

Comment: Super. Glad I could help.